# Process RabbitMQ messages during Spring initialization

Tags: java, spring, amqp

My application has several parts, one of which is responsible for processing input events and requests that are coming at high rates, and the other - for storing information to DB. Since work with DB takes a long time, the second part works in a separate thread and consumes messages from a queue in RabbitMQ that the first part writes to. Also the first part has a cache of all the data that is stored in DB and it is restored on startup.

But here is a problem: if you kill an application when the queue to the second part is not empty and restart, you won't get the same cache that you had before, but a version of it without new events processed. So, the obvious solution is to wait for the queue to exhaust before restoring the cache, but I didn't manage to do it. Also the cache is used during initialization of another module, so I would like all messages to be processed at a time of startup.

So, is there a way to fully initialize one module and start it's work and continue initialization of other modules on some special signal? If it was possible, I would wait for all events to be processed and stored to DB and after that cache could be fully restored.